# Does a regular parametric surface has a canonical reparametrrization?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, surfaces, curvature, reparameterization-trick

Any regular curve may be parametrized by the arc length (the natural parametrization or the unit speed parametrization).

But I haven't seen an analogous development for regular [parametric surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_surface). I hope we can do this at least for orientable surfaces with no [umbilical points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbilical_point). For such a surface, there will be two orthogonal lines of curvature through each point, and I suspect that there is a parametrization whose parametric curves coincide with lines of curvature. But I'm not sure how I should approach showing the existence of such a re-parametrization.

- Is there a such parametrization?
- If not, what are the conditions that we should impose to have such a parametrization?

Comment: Even better, every (sufficiently smooth) has “isothermal parameters” — i.e., a parametrization where the first fundamental form has $E=G$ and $F=0$. But reparametrizing explicitly is harder even than in the case of curves.

Comment: Yes, again, in principle, away from umbilics you can parametrize so that the parameter curves are lines of curvature. See DoCarmo or p. 119-120 of my diff geo text, linked in my profile,

Comment: @TedShifrin: Your comment provides exactly the answer I was looking for "isothermal parameters". If you can write this as an answer, I am more than happy to accept and this question will not be in the unanswered line anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, every (sufficiently smooth) surface admits *isothermal parameters* — i.e., a parametrization in which the first fundamental form has $E=G$ and $F=0$. (That is, it is conformally flat.) An explicit such reparametrization is typically much harder than the parametrization of curves by arclength.